# When might you use multi flash on a speedlight?

Tags: flash, hotshoe-flash, stroboscopic-flash

On my speedlight I have several settings for multi flash, mostly to do with how many flashes and how fast they are fired.

When might you use multi flash? The only thing I can think of is cases where you want to expose a moving object several times during the same exposure.

Answer (score -1):

Apert from showing motion stages of continuous activities or for special effects the multi-flash mode is the least useful.

I am sure it was developed to allow the photography of a golf swing in one still frame :-)

If multi-flash is used with multiple off-camera units it is possible to observe issues with synchronicity of all the slave flashes.

Comment: Isn't that like saying *Apart from the situations where the feature is useful, it's not a useful feature*?